# OpenVPN - user access policy

Tags: openvpn

i just installed openvpn AS on an ubuntu distribution. I applied a group policy access to restrict the access to only one server for this group. Then i assigned the user in the group, but it looks like the access control does not work ... my user can reach every server in the private subnet reachable by openvpn. Is there anything special to allow access to only one ressource ?

Thanks very much.

Alex

Answer (score 1):

ok, i found the answer with the help of a guy from openvpnas irc channel. You can configure in the global access control policy "/32" then add the group authorizations in the group access control policy. You have to use the mask /32 if you want to open the access to one IP address.